# How can I multiple and sum some properties using Linq

Tags: c#, .net, linq-to-sql

I has same a problem. which I want caculator score for student. I done:

```
var cosrse = from ssh in cn.DB.ScoreSheets 
             where ssh.CourseID == CourseID 
             select new 
             { 
                 Student = ssh.Student.LastName +" "+ ssh.Student.FirstName, 
                 ssh.Student.StudentID, Assignment = ssh.Assignment,
                 Project = ssh.Project,
                 ssh.Midterm,
                 ssh.Endterm,
                 ssh.Practice,
                 FinalMatch = ssh.Midterm * 0.2 + ssh.Project * 0.3 + 
                              ssh.Endterm * 0.5 //  new a propety FinalMatch 
              };
```

I want to add column FinalMatch and assign : `ssh.Midterm * 0.2 + ssh.Project * 0.3 + ssh.Endterm * 0.5`  But I don't get any result for FinalMatch.
In here, I has select from two table: [Student],[ScoreSheet] all table have recors. I want to enter score for student and caculater fina match.
Forward to receiving your solutions
Respectfully william!

Comment: If you (temporarily) remove the FinalMatch field, do you get any results? I think maybe it's not the calculation.

Comment: As a sidenote, `Project = ssh.Project,` is useless, simply do `ssh.Project,`

Comment: I tried the same query as you but I am getting results are you sure that all rows for score have entries? Is `FinalMatch` null or something else...

Comment: Yes, when I temporatily remove the FinalMatch field then I has got result.
Now I don't know how can I caculator for the FinalMatch field.

Comment: Is 'Project' a double or int? Seems odd to have something with that name in a score calculation.

Comment: @HenkHolterman: never done a poject in school where you got a grade?

Comment: Are `Midterm`, `Project`, or `Endterm` nullable values? If they are, do any of the records have a null value rather than a number?

Comment: I just wrote up a simple query similar to yours and I'm getting results. Were you able to solve your problem?

Comment: thank everyone, I fixed this error, As thibodeaux said then if Midtern, Project or Endtern is nullable => result is null. Examble 10 + null = null

Answer (score 0):

If this is translated to SQL, you can get some nasty 0 (zero) results when one or more values are `null`.